# npm install unmet dependencies

Tags: npm, vuejs2, npm-install

I'm trying to install vue-pagination-2 (https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2) in my application.

I run the following command:

```
npm install --save vue-pagination-2
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
my_project/myProject
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@3.19.0
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY vue@2.2.6
```

So I run:

```
npm install --save vue@2.2.6
```

But I get exactly the same error.
How can vue@2.2.6 be an unmet dependency since I'm installing exactly that package?
I have already tried to delete node_modules folder and running npm install again.

How can I solve this?

Moreover my package.json file already have those version installed:

```
   "eslint": "^3.19.0",
   "vue": "^2.2.6",
```